# Keyboard shortcuts for setting view angle

Tags: gazebo-camera, gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for quickly switching the camera view to +/- X/Y/Z. There are times when I want to view a model orthogonally from the top down along the Z-axis, and it can literally take minutes of scrolling, and even then it doesn't seem completely possible with the mouse.

Also, is there any way to make a glyph show up indicating the origination of the axis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8422/keyboard-shortcuts-for-setting-view-angle/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Both these features are currently being implemented and should be available from Gazebo 6.

[Orthogonal views](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1507/model-editor-add-buttons-to-change-to)

[World origin indicator](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1551/create-a-world-origin-indicator)

If you have more feature requests, feel free to create issues for them on Gazebo's [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues?status=new&status=open) repository ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0